# When do I capitalize supreme court?

Tags: grammar, capitalization

I have learned that **Supreme Court** is a proper noun and capitalized when I am referring to the United States Supreme Court. However, does this mean that when I am not referencing **the U.S. Federal Supreme Court**. But to an **unknown state supreme court**...then this means I **lowercase supreme court** as in the sentence below:

Sentence: He handed up the indictment to **the supreme court.**
Note: Here I am referencing **an unspecified state supreme court** so does this mean that supreme court is lowercased?**strong text**

Answer (score 1):

The legal convention in the US is to capitalize 'Supreme Court': in legal documents when: 1. When you’re referring to the United States Supreme Court. 2.  When stating a court’s full name: *the Michigan Supreme Court*.

[When should you capitalise 'Court'?](https://www.lawprose.org/lawprose-lesson-131-when-should-you-capitalize-court/)

Answer (score 0):

If you say "the supreme court" (capitalised or not) in a document written in America, without further context, it will be interpreted as "The Supreme Court of the United States". So you should probably say  "to the state supreme court".

You don't need to capitalise this, (eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_supreme_court) but it isn't a big mistake if you write "State Supreme Court".

It is a rather unusual case. Normally you know the state and you would prefer to write, for example, "the Wisconsin Supreme Court" or "the Supreme Court of California" (and that would be capitalised)